# Reduce the space between label and item in a description list

Tags: spacing, description

I have description lists that I'm using discursively, like

```
\begin{description}
    \item[Video recordings] arguably produced the richest part of the data set.
    \item[Questionnaires] were no second, mind you!
\end{description}
```

Unfortunately this renders with a space between the label and the item that is larger than the regular space between words on the same line:

[image: An example of a description list in LaTeX.]

Is there anything I can do to make that space between "Video recordings" and "arguably" equal to that between "arguably" and "produced" and so on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{description}[labelsep=\fontdimen2\font]
    \item[Video recordings] arguably produced the richest part of the data set.
    \item[Questionnaires] were no second, mind you!
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

To control the space between the label and the item, you can change the `labelsep` parameter of the `description` list (available from the `enumitem` package). To obtain the regular word spacing, you need `\fontdimen2` (the normal interword space) for `labelsep`. This is done by passing:

```
[labelsep=\fontdimen2\font]
```

as an option to the `description` environment.

Comment: This will not stretch or shrink, so it won't actually be like the other interword spaces in the line unless the item is just one line long or you're *very* lucky.

Answer (score 2):

Loading `enumitem`, you can play with `labelsep`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}[labelsep=0pt]
    \item[Video recordings] arguably produced the richest part of the data set.
    \item[Questionnaires] were no second, mind you!
\end{description}


\begin{description}[labelsep=2cm]
    \item[Video recordings] arguably produced the richest part of the data set.
    \item[Questionnaires] were no second, mind you!
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Apparently our solutions weren't acceptable ;-) (+1)

Comment: @Christian Hupfer: What the O.P. wanted was not very explicit, but AboAmmar was smarter than us – he guessed.

Comment: Yes, the question was not very clear

Answer (score 2):

It's possible, by stretching a bit the list model; in the case of `description` it's not really a big problem ***provided*** you don't nest enumerated lists inside `description`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for context

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{description}
  {\list{}{%
    \labelwidth\z@
    \itemindent-\leftmargin
    \labelsep=\z@
    \let\makelabel\descriptionlabel
    \let\item\desc@item
  }}
  {\endlist}
\def\desc@item[#1]{\@item[#1]\ \ignorespaces}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum*[2]
\begin{description}

\item[Video recordings] arguably produced the richest part of the data set.

\item[Questionnaires] were no second, mind you! Some text that should
  make the~text~wrap over a couple of lines

\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A magnified view (click on it for even higher resolution)

[image]

Comment: @ChristianHupfer You need glasses.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I'll add a high resolution screenshot.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer The distances are *supposed* to be different!

Answer (score 0):

A mild alternative to [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/266765/5764) if you want to intermix the regular `description` with a modified `bfdesc`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paper=a6paper,showframe]{geometry}% Just for this example

\newenvironment{bfdesc}
  {\begin{description}
   \let\olditem\item
   \renewcommand{\item}[1][]{%
     \olditem% Set old \item without [..]
     \hspace*{-\labelsep}% Remove \labelsep
     {\bfseries ##1}% Set new \item
     \space% Insert space (\ )
     \ignorespaces}}% Ignore any following spaces
  {\end{description}}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
  \item[Video recordings] arguably produced the richest part of the data set.
  \item[Questionnaires] were no second, mind you!
\end{description}

\begin{bfdesc}
  \item[Video recordings] arguably produced the richest part of the data set.
  \item[Questionnaires] were no second, mind you!
\end{bfdesc}

\end{document}
```